# difference between group sums pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

DF:

```
    fruits     date      amount
0   Apple   2018-01-01   100
1   Orange  2018-01-01   200
2   Apple   2018-01-01   150
3   Apple   2018-01-02   100
4   Orange  2018-01-02   100
5   Orange  2018-01-02   100
```

Code to create this:

```
f = [["Apple","2018-01-01",100],["Orange","2018-01-01",200],["Apple","2018-01-01",150],
 ["Apple","2018-01-02",100],["Orange","2018-01-02",100],["Orange","2018-01-02",100]]
df = pd.DataFrame(f,columns = ["fruits","date","amount"])
```

I am trying to aggregate the sale of fruits for each date and find the difference between sums

Expected Op:

```
date          diff
2018-01-01 .   50 
2018-01-02 .  -100
```

As in find the sum of sales of Apple and orange and find the difference between the sums

I am able to find the sum:

```
df.groupby(["date","fruits"])["amount"].agg("sum") 

   date        fruits
 2018-01-01    Apple     250
               Orange    200
 2018-01-02    Apple     100
               Orange    200
  Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Any suggestions on how to find the difference in pandas itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` `date` and `apply` using `lambda function` as:

```
df.groupby("date").apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['fruits']=='Apple','amount'].sum() - 
                                   x.loc[x['fruits']=='Orange','amount'].sum())

date
2018-01-01     50
2018-01-02   -100
dtype: int64
```

Or grouping the fruits separately and finding the difference:

```
A = df[df.fruits.isin(['Apple'])].groupby('date')['amount'].sum()
O = df[df.fruits.isin(['Orange'])].groupby('date')['amount'].sum()

O-A
date
2018-01-01    -50
2018-01-02    100
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please [`upvote`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the solution provided your required result.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_diff(grp):
    grp = grp.groupby('fruits').agg(sum)['amount'].values
    return grp[0] - grp[1]

df.groupby('date').apply(get_diff)
```

**Output**

```
date
2018-01-01     50
2018-01-02   -100
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape and then subtract with [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns:

```
df = df.groupby(["date","fruits"])["amount"].sum().unstack()
df['diff'] = df.pop('Apple') - df.pop('Orange')
print (df)
fruits      diff
date            
2018-01-01    50
2018-01-02  -100
```